# wordpress - get thumbnail size from thumbnail name/reference

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

I have set up a thumbnail like

`add_image_size( 'banner_image', 1098, 400, true );`

now after this is registered I want to be able to get the dimensions from the reference, i.e.

```
get_thumbnail_size( 'banner_image' )
{

}
```

is there anyway of doing this?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

echo $_wp_additional_image_sizes['banner_image']['width'];   // output width
echo $_wp_additional_image_sizes['banner_image']['height'];  // output height
```